# After removing double entries I also lost some other elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I've a vrey big xml file. I try to generate a leigther xml file to use it in extracting datas with SSIS.

My file contains several cases. I put each case [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2A/1)

I extract 4 cases that I simplify

```
 <ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
 <files.index Generated="20150916022750">
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/29799266.xml" Product_ID="29799266" Updated="20150915223003" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="25" Prod_ID="89811499" Catid="827" On_Market="0" Model_Name="AmazonLED" Product_View="0" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/29799266_6440.jpg" HighPicSize="189800" HighPicWidth="2000" HighPicHeight="2000" Date_Added="20150915000000"></file>
 <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml" Product_ID="4312841" Updated="20150523100119" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="30" Prod_ID="003R92156" Catid="197" On_Market="1" Model_Name="3640" Product_View="32767" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/4312841-1574.jpg" HighPicSize="289900" HighPicWidth="1552" HighPicHeight="1200" Date_Added="20100306000000">
  <M_Prod_ID>DOCUMATE 3640</M_Prod_ID>
  <M_Prod_ID>003R92156</M_Prod_ID>
</file>
 <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml" Product_ID="26064804" Updated="20150827060248" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="30097568" Catid="2943" On_Market="0" Model_Name="Color Show 110 Urban Coral" Product_View="2819" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/26064804-6070.jpg" HighPicSize="34989" HighPicWidth="400" HighPicHeight="355" Date_Added="20150127000000">
      <M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>
      <M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>
</file>
<file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml" Product_ID="4312841" Updated="20150523100119" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="30" Prod_ID="dfqsdfqfq6" Catid="197" On_Market="1" Model_Name="3640" Product_View="32767" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/4312841-1574.jpg" HighPicSize="289900" HighPicWidth="1552" HighPicHeight="1200" Date_Added="20100306000000">
  <M_Prod_ID Supplier_id="670" Supplier_name="Visioneer">dfqsdfqfq6</M_Prod_ID>
</file>
</files.index>
</ICECAT-interface>
```

My xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ICECAT-interface">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="files.index"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="files.index">
    <xsl:element name="files">
        <xsl:attribute name="Generated">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Generated"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:element name="file">
        <xsl:attribute name="path">
            <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Prod_ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Prod_ID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Supplier_id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Supplier_id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Catid">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Catid"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Updated">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Updated"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Quality">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Quality"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="M_Prod_ID"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID" />

<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)]">
    <file path="{../@path}" Prod_ID="{.}" Catid="../@Catid" Updated="../@Updated" Quality="../@Quality">

        <xsl:attribute name="Supplier_id">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Supplier_id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Supplier_id"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@Supplier_id"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </file>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result

```
 <files Generated="20150916022750">
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/29799266.xml"
     Prod_ID="89811499"
     Supplier_id="25"
     Catid="827"
     Updated="20150915223003"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="003R92156"
     Supplier_id="30"
     Catid="197"
     Updated="20150523100119"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="DOCUMATE 3640"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="30"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="30097568"
     Supplier_id="11077"
     Catid="2943"
     Updated="20150827060248"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="0000030097568"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="11077"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="0000030097568"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="11077"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="dfqsdfqfq6"
     Supplier_id="30"
     Catid="197"
     Updated="20150523100119"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
  </files>
```

The 2 problem are

```
<file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="0000030097568"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="11077"/>
```

Repeated twice.

and last row isn't duplicate with Supplier_Id=670

In precedent question. @Abel says use

```
 <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[text() = following-sibling::M_Prod_ID/text()]">
```

result [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2A/2)

Then It's Ok for file node repeated twice but I lost file node with

```
<file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="DOCUMATE 3640"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="30"/>
```

How Can I Mixe ths two solutions ?
Others says use Grouping. But I don't know how it's run for my case.

### Update

I want

```
<files Generated="20150916022750">
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/29799266.xml"
     Prod_ID="89811499"
     Supplier_id="25"
     Catid="827"
     Updated="20150915223003"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="003R92156"
     Supplier_id="30"
     Catid="197"
     Updated="20150523100119"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="DOCUMATE 3640"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="30"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="30097568"
     Supplier_id="11077"
     Catid="2943"
     Updated="20150827060248"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
     Prod_ID="0000030097568"
     Catid="../@Catid"
     Updated="../@Updated"
     Quality="../@Quality"
     Supplier_id="11077"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="dfqsdfqfq6"
     Supplier_id="30"
     Catid="197"
     Updated="20150523100119"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml"
     Prod_ID="dfqsdfqfq6"
     Supplier_id="670"
     Catid="197"
     Updated="20150523100119"
     Quality="ICECAT"/>
</files>
```

Comment: As Michael suggested in the other question, take a moment to create a [mcve]. You did that (except for the minimal), and it is good you pasted a link to it, it helps us understand, but that link will be temporary. So please _also paste the minimal set that demonstrates your problem_ in the issue. In addition, show what you want as correct output, the text "I lost a node with X" is not clear enough (otherwise we'll end up having such long discussions again... ;).

Comment: I insert my code. It's for me the minima (I remove lot of unused field and take only 4 lines on more 4 000 000) And I add the result I Want. I hope it's good now?

Comment: Yes, definitely **much** better! Now at least it is crystal clear what you want (haven't tested it yet, but I assume you did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now becomes clear what you want and I think the solution is easier than it may have looked when you first posted the question. Many thanks for showing the relevant code.

This code

> ```
>  <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[text() = following-sibling::M_Prod_ID/text()]">
> ```

was testing duplicates between two sibling `M_Prod_ID`, but it did not assume that these may appear once as well.

The solution to this in XSLT 1.0 is not as simple as one might think and it shows why Michael suggested to go for Muenchian grouping. Here's the non-Muenchian way:

```
<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)][following-sibling::M_Prod_ID][text() = following-sibling::M_Prod_ID/text()]" priority="5"/>
```

And here is it applied to a simplified version of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICECAT-interface">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="files.index"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="files.index">
        <files Generated="{@Generated}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
        </files>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <file path="{@path}" Prod_ID="{@Prod_ID}" Supplier_id="{@Supplier_id}" Catid="{@Catid}" Updated="{@Updated}" Quality="{@Quality}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="M_Prod_ID"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)][following-sibling::M_Prod_ID][text() = following-sibling::M_Prod_ID/text()]" priority="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)]">
        <file path="{../@path}" Prod_ID="{.}" Catid="../@Catid" Updated="../@Updated" Quality="../@Quality">
            <xsl:copy-of select="parent::*[not(current()/@Supplier_id)]/@Supplier_id | @Supplier_id" />
        </file>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this transformation is the following, which is almost the same as your result, because some business rules were not explained (mainly the last file, but I'm sure you can work that out).

```
<files Generated="20150916022750">
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/29799266.xml" Prod_ID="89811499" Supplier_id="25" Catid="827" Updated="20150915223003" Quality="ICECAT" />
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml" Prod_ID="003R92156" Supplier_id="30" Catid="197" Updated="20150523100119" Quality="ICECAT" />
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml" Prod_ID="DOCUMATE 3640" Catid="197" Updated="20150523100119" Quality="ICECAT" />
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml" Prod_ID="30097568" Supplier_id="11077" Catid="2943" Updated="20150827060248" Quality="ICECAT" />
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml" Prod_ID="0000030097568" Catid="2943" Updated="20150827060248" Quality="ICECAT" />
  <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/4312841.xml" Prod_ID="dfqsdfqfq6" Supplier_id="30" Catid="197" Updated="20150523100119" Quality="ICECAT" />
</files>
```

In your original post you wrote this as wanted result for some attributes.

```
 Catid="../@Catid"
 Updated="../@Updated"
 Quality="../@Quality"
```

I assumed that was incorrect and turned them into AVT's.

And as a giveaway, this is how I turned your stylesheet from using `xsl:attribute` to AVT syntax (uses XSLT 3.0, but can trivially be adopted to XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />

    <xsl:template match="xsl:element">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:element/xsl:attribute">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@name}" select="'{'||xsl:value-of/@select||'}'"/>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:element/text()[not(normalize-space(.))]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wouah!!!! It's perfect... Can you explain why you put ' <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID"/>
    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)][following-sibling::M_Prod_ID][text() = following-sibling::M_Prod_ID/text()]" priority="5"/>' Cause I'm Happy it work, but If I can understand a bit more xslt ...

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, give me a moment, I'll update. I always like it when people ask for explanation of code :). PS: you should use backticks `\`code here\`` when quoting code in comments, it makes it (a little bit) more readable.